# Allow user to write in a programmatically created Excel sheet without closing the userform

Tags: vba, excel

I programmatically create a new Excel sheet within my VBA application when the user clicks on a button. I would like to allow the user to write this newly created sheet and keep the userform of creation of new sheets displayed in the same time.

EDIT : Additional precision : I use a succession of userforms, the first one is an authentification form, the second one is a functionnality selection menu and the one I mentionned in my question offers one of those functionnalities. Therefore the correct solution to my problem was to show all these user-forms as non-modals.

Comment: @AxelRichter you can define this property when the `.Show` method is invoked. If you type `.Show` and then a space, you'll see the IntelliSense hint pop up with the optional modal argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the userform as non-modal:

```
Userform1.Show False '//<-- Allows user interaction whilst form is active.
```

---

***Caveat:***
*Displaying a form as non-modal will allow code execution to resume after the form is displayed - this could result in unexpected behavior and should be considered at design time. For example:*

```
Sub ModalExample()

UserForm1.Show '// Show modal, code will pause here until form is closed.
MsgBox "Userform has now been closed."

UserForm1.Show False '// Show non-modal, code will continue to execute regardless.
MsgBox "Userform is still open."

End Sub
```

Comment: I get this error message when trying your solution : "Runtime Error '401': Can't show non-modal form when modal form is displayed."

Comment: use that line to actually display the form initially - not once it's been displayed.

Comment: would the down-voter care to explain why this is a bad answer?

Comment: It still doesn't work. Maybe the problem is that I use several userforms, I have a userform that displays another one on click on a button.

Comment: You would need to display all forms as non-modal for this to work. Perhaps you could update your original question to let people know?

Comment: Just be aware however, that a non-modal form will allow code execution to resume if there is any. This is important to consider at design time.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, can you give more precisions to the newbie I am ?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is wrong. The following line of code is incorrect:

```
Userform1.Show False
```

The suggestion to display the userform modelessly is a good one for this question's scenario, but to be correct it should be done like so:

```
Userform1.Show vbModeless   <---This is correct.
```

It is true that both False and vbModeless evaluate to the value zero. HOWEVER, that's just coincidence.

For example, if you were to try the inverse to display the userform modally, it would not work:

```
Userform1.Show True   <---This does NOT work.
```

But this does:

```
Userform1.Show vbModal
```

Never use Boolean values as an argument to a userform's Show method. Instead use the members of the FormShowConstants enum.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure that if a userform is active then it will not allow you to access the worksheet until it is closed.

Couple of ways around this though. Hide the userform until it is needed again. Set it to a keyboard shortcut or something to show it again. So it would be `userform.hide` then have another macro or a button in the ribbon to show the userform again by using `userform.show`

Instead of creating a new sheet. Create a new instance of Excel with a new workbook. That would allow the userform to stay open in one Excel instance and then the user can write to the other workbook in the other instance of Excel

To create a new instance of Excel you would need to use the code

```
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application 
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

objExcel.Workbooks.Add 

objExcel.Visible = True
```

That will create a new Excel instance and still have the userform in the other instance of Excel

Comment: Can you give more precisions about how to create a new instance of Excel with a new workbook (I'm very new to VBA programming). What I do for now is  :  Set newWorkBook = Workbooks.Add, ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs newFilePath

Comment: You can get around this by hiding the userform as you say, however that command would be `Userform.Hide` as `.Show` is a method, not a property, so it's value cannot be set to true or false. I would strongly advise against working with another instance of Excel if you want to use VBA unless you understand the relevant API functions that are required to control the other instance.

Comment: @SOofWXLS, yes I did mean hide. not chaning the show value. Thank you for setting that straight.

Comment: @otus I have updated my answer to show how to create a new one. You can control it in VBA if you still need to by using the objExcel as a workbook. So to access it, it would be something like objExcel.sheets(1).range("A1").value = "TEST" that shows you can easily control. I am not sure why I have so many down votes on my answer though...