# Edit an excel file while having a user form open

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

my actual situation is:

1. I open one excel file
2. I Click on a complement, which is a .xla, and this .xla opens a userform
3. Then I fill in that userform during some hours of work

The problem is that sometimes I need to edit past data from other days before but I need to close the user form and all the information that I had already filled is lost.

I've tried all these:

1. Insert a command button in the userform to hide it but when I reload it from the complement, everything is lost
2. Insert a command button in the userform to hide it and put a 60 seconds timer to show it again, but I can't edit the excel
3. Insert a command button in the userform with a timer and use the ShowModal property as here below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim PauseTime, Start, Finish, TotalTime
If (MsgBox("Pulsa Yes para editar la hoja a mano", 4)) = vbYes Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    UserForm1.Hide
    UserForm1.Show False
    PauseTime = 10    ' Set duration.
    Start = Timer    ' Set start time.
    Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
        DoEvents    ' Yield to other processes.
    Loop
    Finish = Timer
    UserForm1.Hide
    UserForm1.Show
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Else
    End
End If

End Sub
```

4. Turn the ShowModal property to false directly at the beginning, but the it doesn't show at all.

Could someone help me with this, please? I'm kind of lost now...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `UserForm1.Show 0` which will show the form as modeless and should allow you to access other parts of the application whilst open - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/show-method
Note: The userform will not appear on the taskbar (by default - you need to code it to appear) so it's easily lost behind application windows etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow user to write in a programmatically created Excel sheet without closing the userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913849/allow-user-to-write-in-a-programmatically-created-excel-sheet-without-closing-th)

Comment: You could add a pause and resume function to your form.  The "pause" should save the current values of all the controls on your form in a temporary sheet or in document properties or as global variables in your xla.  You could then allow the user to shut down the form.  The "resume" option in the UserForm_Initialize would need to recognise that a pause status existed and populate the controls accordingly.  The difficulty of doing all this depends to a large extent on the structure of your form.  If it is mostly simple controls, it could all be done with a couple of fairly simple loops.